# Unable to get-credentials-for-identity for an AWS Cognito Developer Authenticated Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, identity-provider

I understand from [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-2-developer-authenticated-identities/) that exchanging OpenID tokens for AWS Credentials is supposed to be done by the Client/End-User Device.

But as a POC/Demo, I am trying to generate temporary AWS Creds completely Backend side.
As such I have the following Identity Pool and Role in my Cloudformation template:

```yaml
Resources:
  KvsIdentityPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
    Properties:
      AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: False
      IdentityPoolName: KVS_ID_POOL_POC

  KvsIdentityPoolAuthenticatedRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: esp-KvsIdentityPoolAuthenticatedRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Federated: cognito-identity.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
              - sts:TagSession
            Condition:
              StringEquals:
                cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud: !Ref KvsIdentityPool
              ForAnyValue:StringLike:
                cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr: !Ref DevProviderName
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: IdentityPoolAuthenticatedRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - cognito-identity:GetCredentialsForIdentity
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "kinesisvideo:Describe*"
                  - "kinesisvideo:Get*"
                  - "kinesisvideo:List*"
                Resource: "*"
```

I get the OpenID token and IdentityId on running:

```bash
aws cognito-identity get-open-id-token-for-developer-identity --identity-pool-id 'IdentityPoolId' --logins '{"DevProviderName":"<Some User's Cognito UserID>"}'
```

But when I try to exchange that using
`aws cognito-identity get-credentials-for-identity --identity-id "<Freshly Generated Identity ID>"`

I get:
`An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the GetCredentialsForIdentity operation: Access to Identity '<Freshly Generated Identity ID>' is forbidden.`